# Git add terminated

Tags: linux, git, github, vps

I installed git on my linux VPS and now im trying yo add a folder to my repository with "git add myfolder/*" but the terminal just returns "Terminated"

Anyone know why this happens?

I just started looking at git today, I've been using SVN for years with out any problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that i had a relatively large .zip file in the folder i was trying to add. After I removed the .zip file it solved the problem

Comment: Interesting. More specific than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a folder, you can simply type:

```
git add myfolder
```

(no need for the `/*`)

See [`git add` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> Also a leading directory name (e.g. `dir` to add `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to add all files in the directory, recursively.

Comment: I tried typing `git add folder` but the result is the same, the process does not even start and it just says `Terminated`

Comment: if I try typing `git add folder/fileinfolder.php` then it adds it just fine

Comment: @Oldenborg what git version are you using (`git --version`), and on what OS are you (Linux, but which version?). Your folder is within the git working tree, right?